# What does bootstrap means in a AngularJs's context?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in AngularJs, and I was reading this tutorial for begginers http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html .

Somewhere the author says "...When we refresh the page, Angular will bootstrap myApp.".

What exactly this means?

I know bootstrap method in statistics, I know the Bootsrap3, but I can not understand what boostarp means in this context.
Can someone explain?

Comment: I found it unnecessary of Google to use 'bootstrap' to essentially describe the 'pairing of the two'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrapping Angular means starting up a Angular Application. It can be automatic or you can do it manually by calling the method `angular.bootstrap`. From the docs:

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is 
>   evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'. At
>   this point Angular looks for the ng-app directive which designates
>   your application root. If the ng-app directive is found then Angular
>   will:
>
> 1. load the module associated with the directive.
> 2. create the application injector
> 3. compile the DOM treating the ng-app directive as the root of the compilation. This allows you to > tell it to treat only a portion of the DOM as an Angular application.

You can read more on the docs: [Bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)